# Laravel: parse JSON to view

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm trying to show JSON data from this https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json, but I got an error:

`(ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined index: confirmed`

What I expect is I can show the list of Country Name following with the Date, Confirmed, etc.

Here's my view:

```
@foreach($results as $json_d)

  {{ $json_d['date'] }}
  {{ $json_d['confirmed'] }}
  {{ $json_d['deaths'] }}
  {{ $json_d['recovered'] }}

@endforeach
```

And here's my controller:

```
$client = new Client();

$request = $client->get('https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json');
$response = $request->getBody()->getContents();
$results = json_decode($response, true);

return view('dashboard', compact('results'));
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Is `confirmed` the only index with the warning and the others are fine?

Comment: the others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have to do it as a `nested for`. As the answer of Dino, but there's the way of get the country key.

```
  @foreach($results as $key => $val)
      Data for the country: {{ $key }}
    @foreach(((array)$results)[$key] as $data)
        {{ $data['date'] }}
        {{ $data['confirmed'] }}
        {{ $data['deaths'] }}
        {{ $data['recovered'] }}
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
```

Comment: I wonder is it possible to count the total 'confirmed' by country?

Comment: Something like this? http://codebin.herokuapp.com?s=5e74df229d891f0004000002

Answer (score 0):

The result you get with Guzzle is a list of countries

```
dd($results);
```

gives

```
array:152 [▼
  "Thailand" => array:57 [▶]
  "Japan" => array:57 [▶]
  "Singapore" => array:57 [▶]
  "Nepal" => array:57 [▶]
  "Malaysia" => array:57 [▶]
  "Canada" => array:57 [▶]
  "Australia" => array:57 [▶]
  "Cambodia" => array:57 [▶]
  "Sri Lanka" => array:57 [▶]
  "Germany" => array:57 [▶]
  "Finland" => array:57 [▶]
  ...
```

which means you need another loop

```
@foreach($results as $countryData)
   @foreach($countryData as $data)
       {{ $data['date'] }}
       {{ $data['confirmed'] }}
       {{ $data['deaths'] }}
       {{ $data['recovered'] }}
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: this is also correct! but I need to show the country name as well. thank you